# Why is my quiche soggy?

Tags: baking, eggs, crust, quiche

I have tried making the same quiche recipe twice, but both times it has turned out soggy. I whisked together 3 eggs, milk, half and half, and seasonings and poured it over the crust with ham and cheese sitting at the bottom. I put it in the oven at 375 for an hour. Everything was cooked, but there was liquid just coming out of it and the bottom crust was soggy. Any ideas why this sogginess is occurring?

Comment: did you blind-bake the crust first? Were there any vegetables in the filling?

Comment: What kind of milk did you use? What fat content? Try cutting back the milk a bit.

Comment: I did not blind-bake it. I used low fat milk.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you've forgotten (or not been directed) to blind-bake the crust. Blind-baking is baking a crust without a filling so that it gets a head start, sealing it and preventing it going soggy.

To blind-bake, place the pastry in the dish as usual, dot the base with a fork in a few places, then cut a square of baking paper roughly the same size as the dish, place it on the pastry, and add some baking weights (small ceramic balls) or dry kidney beans. These stop the pastry from bubbling up.

Place in a pre-heated oven for about 20 minutes until the crust is lightly golden. Remove from the oven, remove the weights and paper (if using kidney beans, you can use them again, but don't cook them to eat!) and let the crust cool for 30 minutes before adding the filling and completing the baking process.

Comment: actually, i'd bet on too much milk over not blind baking the crust.

Comment: Custard has considerably more moisture in than a quiche, but blind baking prevents that crust  from being a soggy mess.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your recipe for the royal--- you're using "half-and-half" and milk --- so something like 3 parts milk to 1 part cream. You should try using just heavy cream for the royal. It's not a health food--and if you want to be healthier, just eat a smaller piece.

Also the pre-baking of the crust may be needed, depending on thickness of crust and height of the quiche.